# Calculate a value in a column for each row

Tags: r

Here is the table that I am trying to manipulate:

```
colnames sampA sampB
#1       conA  conB
#2       1.1   4.4
#3       2.2   5.5
#4       3.3   6.6
```

I want to calculate log2(x(1-x)) for each number in $sampB. Here is my code so far:

```
 DF[-1,3] <- apply(DF[-1,]$sampB,1,function(x) log2(x(1-x)))
```

then I got the error message:

```
     dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Comment: What is the result from `sapply(DF, class)`?

Comment: Hi, @RichardScriven I tried a function without log2(), like just x+1, it showed the same error msg. and conA and conB is just some text in the original data. I dont need them for calculation but I might need them later.

Comment: Okay then I think my answer below would work.  It removes the first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `apply()`, as `log2()` is vectorized.  Try this

```
x <- as.numeric(as.character(DF$sampB[-1]))
log2(x * (1 - x))
```

I took off the first element because I'm not really sure what that `conB` part is about (and now you have confirmed it in the comments). I also suspect that the column might be a factor (because of `conB`), so I wrapped the column in `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.  That may not be necessary, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Came in a factor when I imported it so `as.numeric(as.character(...))` is probably necessary.